Problem having offline installation of Visual Studio 2022 community
I've downloaded a copy with the packages that I need, to install it in an offline machine.
After finishing the download from Microsoft site this is the result:
enter image description here
The problem is that there is only folders and no installer file to install the package.
How I will install this package in an offline machine not connected to the net???

If you go into Common7, there should be an IDE folder, and in that, a devenv.exe.  Is that present? If so, run that .exe.  That should open visual studio

To perform a local network installation, you need to use the VS bootstrapper to download a layout.After downloading it should look like this:
Full detailed guide could be found here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022
The layout file varies based on the number of components you have selected,and the full layout could reach 70 gigs.Make sure you have sufficient disk space before deployment.
